# CMAK/ Kafka-UI wont reslove local host

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, yahoo-kafka-manager

I want to connect my CMAK to my Kafka docker server. But it wont resolve the localhost for the zookeeper. I tried to edit the address in the config file as i think i should. when i put in "localhost:2181" it doesn't work. I also tried 0.0.0.0:2181.

Java 11
Python 3

My producer and consumer work as they should.

Here is my code:

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: broker
    ports:
    # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
    # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 77.247.224.40
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

I used CMAK pulled from git.

Here is the config file(unedited):

```
# Copyright 2015 Yahoo Inc. Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# See accompanying LICENSE file.

# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
# If you deploy your application to several instances be sure to use the same key!
play.crypto.secret="..."
play.crypto.secret=${?APPLICATION_SECRET}
play.http.session.maxAge="1h"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
play.i18n.langs=["en"]

play.http.requestHandler = "play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler"
play.http.context = "/"
play.application.loader=loader.KafkaManagerLoader

# Settings prefixed with 'kafka-manager.' will be deprecated, use 'cmak.' instead.
# https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK/issues/713
kafka-manager.zkhosts="kafka-manager-zookeeper:2181"
kafka-manager.zkhosts=${?ZK_HOSTS}
cmak.zkhosts="kafka-manager-zookeeper:2181"
cmak.zkhosts=${?ZK_HOSTS}

pinned-dispatcher.type="PinnedDispatcher"
pinned-dispatcher.executor="thread-pool-executor"
application.features=["KMClusterManagerFeature","KMTopicManagerFeature","KMPreferredReplicaElectionFeature","KMReassignPartitionsFeature", "KMScheduleLeaderElectionFeature"]

akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
}

akka.logger-startup-timeout = 60s

basicAuthentication.enabled=false
basicAuthentication.enabled=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_AUTH_ENABLED}

basicAuthentication.ldap.enabled=false
basicAuthentication.ldap.enabled=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_ENABLED}
basicAuthentication.ldap.server=""
basicAuthentication.ldap.server=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_SERVER}
basicAuthentication.ldap.port=389
basicAuthentication.ldap.port=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_PORT}
basicAuthentication.ldap.username=""
basicAuthentication.ldap.username=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_USERNAME}
basicAuthentication.ldap.password=""
basicAuthentication.ldap.password=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_PASSWORD}
basicAuthentication.ldap.search-base-dn=""
basicAuthentication.ldap.search-base-dn=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN}
basicAuthentication.ldap.search-filter="(uid=$capturedLogin$)"
basicAuthentication.ldap.search-filter=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER}
basicAuthentication.ldap.group-filter=""
basicAuthentication.ldap.group-filter=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_GROUP_FILTER}
basicAuthentication.ldap.connection-pool-size=10
basicAuthentication.ldap.connection-pool-size=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE}
basicAuthentication.ldap.ssl=false
basicAuthentication.ldap.ssl=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_SSL}
basicAuthentication.ldap.ssl-trust-all=false
basicAuthentication.ldap.ssl-trust-all=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_LDAP_SSL_TRUST_ALL}

basicAuthentication.username="admin"
basicAuthentication.username=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_USERNAME}
basicAuthentication.password="password"
basicAuthentication.password=${?KAFKA_MANAGER_PASSWORD}

basicAuthentication.realm="Kafka-Manager"
basicAuthentication.excluded=["/api/health"] # ping the health of your instance without authentification


kafka-manager.consumer.properties.file=${?CONSUMER_PROPERTIES_FILE}
```

Thanks for help. :)

The Error message:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-manager-zookeeper
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider$1.getAllByName(StaticHostProvider.java:92)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.resolve(StaticHostProvider.java:147)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider.next(StaticHostProvider.java:375)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1137)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Zookeeper service isn't exposing port 2181 to your host machine.

```
ports:
    - "2181:2181"
```

Then `localhost:2181` is correct unless you're trying to run CMAK as a container too

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but it did not work. Just posted a error message i am getting. Thanks for help

Comment: Your properties file needs to use `localhost:2181`, as answered, and not `kafka-manager-zookeeper:2181`

Comment: I found the problem thanks for your help. Now the problem is to set up JMX port to see the metrics. I now have access to CMAK and it is connected, but as i run any task all the metrics a re still 0. To my docker-compose file i added,       `KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: "9010"`
but my CMAK in broker view shows port to be PLAINTEXT:9092.